# Wildcard variables in xargs for parallel processing

Tags: bash, wildcards, variable-substitution, parallelism

### Issue

I have an issue using an input variable `VAR` in a function (i.e. `ls`) with the wilcard `*`, when this funciton is within an `xargs` bash call.

This `xargs` function repeats over each member of a list of filename prefixes `InfilePrefix_List.csv`.

The input variable `VAR` is a string in the form: `VAR="dir/sub_dir/SharedPrefix_InfilePrefix"`.

`ls ${VAR}*` gives the error that it cannot find the directory as it has read `VAR` incorrectly due to the presence of `*`.

### Solution

In the end, the input list was saved as a .csv file and xargs was reading an additional "\r" after every list entry. There after the .csv file was amended the functions run smoothly.
See same problem here: https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/124289-xargs-appending-r.html

Cheers

### Simplified Example & Parallel Computing

In reality, the function I am using is not `ls`, but is: `cdo ensmean infiles*.nc outfile.nc`, which makes an ensemble mean from multiple replicate climate data files.

However, for this post, the example using `ls infiles*.nc` is fine. Note, I am using `xargs` instead of a for loop alternative as I need to avail of the parallel computing power offered by `xargs --max-procs 44` option.

### Example bash script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
more /dir/subdir/File_Prefix_List.csv |  xargs -I {} bash -c "
echo 'arg is '{};
VAR=\$(echo /dir/subdir/SharedPrefix_{});
echo 'var is '\$VAR;
ls \${VAR}*.nc;
exit 1;"
```

### NOTES

Line 2   - {} represents the specific `InfilePrefix` string

Line 3,5 - echo to check VAR is correct - which it is...

line 6 - example function is `ls`, listing all files that have `SharedPrefix_InfilePrefix` in their name

### Debugging Edit

As requested, here is the output of the sample bash script with this change: `head -n 1 ...<my specific directories>... xargs -I {} bash -vxc " ...`

Note that for my specific case, the difference between the example and the code I have run are: (1) `/dir/subdir = /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau`. (2) `/SharedPrefix_ = /Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_`. (3) `{} = ACCESS-CM2_historical`.

Output: Line 1 & 2: the xargs argument (`{} = ACCESS-CM2_historical`) and directory variable (`VAR = /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical`) are correct. Line 3: there is the error in reading the wildcard.

Section 1 the end of the output showing error messages I thought are relevant.

```
;cho 'arg is 'ACCESS-CM2_historical
' echo 'arg is ACCESS-CM2_historical
arg is ACCESS-CM2_historical
);R=$(echo /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
++ echo $'/nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical\r'
+ VAR=$'/nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical\r'
echo 'var is '$VAR;
' echo 'var is /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
var is /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
ls ${VAR}*.nc;
*.nc''/nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
*.nc: No such file or directory35080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
exit 1;
+ exit 1
```

Section 2 - the full output, some of which I don't understand - not sure if its all relevant - sorry - I am new to Unix!

```
module () {  eval $($LMOD_CMD bash "$@");
 [ $? = 0 ] && eval $(${LMOD_SETTARG_CMD:-:} -s sh)
}
ml () {  eval $($LMOD_DIR/ml_cmd "$@")
}
# -*- shell-script -*-
if [[ ${-/x} != $- ]]; then
   echo "Start of Lmod init/bash script to define the module command"
fi
+ [[ hvBc != hvxBc ]]
+ echo 'Start of Lmod init/bash script to define the module command'
Start of Lmod init/bash script to define the module command


LMOD_PKG=/usr/share/lmod/lmod
+ LMOD_PKG=/usr/share/lmod/lmod
LMOD_DIR=/usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec
+ LMOD_DIR=/usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec
LMOD_CMD=/usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/lmod
+ LMOD_CMD=/usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/lmod
MODULESHOME=/usr/share/lmod/lmod
+ MODULESHOME=/usr/share/lmod/lmod
export LMOD_PKG
+ export LMOD_PKG
export LMOD_CMD
+ export LMOD_CMD
export LMOD_DIR
+ export LMOD_DIR
export MODULESHOME
+ export MODULESHOME

########################################################################
#  Define the module command:  The first line runs the "lmod" command
#  to generate text:
#      export PATH="..."
#  then the "eval" converts the text into changes in the current shell.
#
#  The second command is the settarg command.  Normally LMOD_SETTARG_CMD
#  is undefined or is ":".  Either way the eval does nothing.  When the
#  settarg module is loaded, it defines LMOD_SETTARG_CMD.  The settarg
#  command knows how to read the ModuleTable that Lmod maintains and
#  generates a series of env. vars that describe the current state of
#  loaded modules.  So if one is on a x86_64 linux computer with gcc/4.7.2
#  and openmpi/1.6.3 loaded, then settarg will assign:
#
#     TARG=_x86_64_gcc-4.7.2_openmpi-1.6.3
#     TARG_COMPILER=gcc-4.7.2
#     TARG_COMPILER_FAMILY=gcc
#     TARG_MACH=x86_64
#     TARG_MPI=openmpi-1.6.3
#     TARG_MPI_FAMILY=openmpi
#     TARG_SUMMARY=x86_64_gcc-4.7.2_openmpi-1.6.3
#     TARG_TITLE_BAR=gcc-4.7.2 O-1.6.3
#     TARG_TITLE_BAR_PAREN=(gcc-4.7.2 O-1.6.3)
#
#  unloading openmpi/1.6.3 automatically changes these vars to be:
#
#     TARG=_x86_64_gcc-4.6.3
#     TARG_COMPILER=gcc-4.6.3
#     TARG_COMPILER_FAMILY=gcc
#     TARG_MACH=x86_64
#     TARG_SUMMARY=x86_64_gcc-4.6.3
#     TARG_TITLE_BAR=gcc-4.6.3
#     TARG_TITLE_BAR_PAREN=(gcc-4.6.3)
#
# See Lmod web site for more details.

module()
{
  eval $($LMOD_CMD bash "$@")
  [ $? = 0 ] && eval $(${LMOD_SETTARG_CMD:-:} -s sh)
}

LMOD_VERSION="6.5.1"
+ LMOD_VERSION=6.5.1
export LMOD_VERSION
+ export LMOD_VERSION

if [ "${LMOD_SETTARG_CMD:-:}" != ":" ]; then
  settarg () {
    eval $(${LMOD_SETTARG_CMD:-:} -s sh "$@" )
  }
fi
+ '[' : '!=' : ']'


########################################################################
#  ml is a shorthand tool for people who can't type moduel, err, module
#  It is also a combination command:
#     ml            -> module list
#     ml gcc        -> module load gcc
#     ml -gcc intel -> module unload gcc; module load intel
#  It does much more do: "ml --help" for more information.


unalias ml 2> /dev/null || true
+ unalias ml
+ true
ml()
{
  eval $($LMOD_DIR/ml_cmd "$@")
}

export_module=$(echo "YES" | /usr/bin/tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
++ echo YES
++ /usr/bin/tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
+ export_module=yes
if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION:-}" -a "$export_module" != no ]; then
  export -f module
  export -f ml
fi
+ '[' -n '4.2.46(2)-release' -a yes '!=' no ']'
+ export -f module
+ export -f ml
unset export_module
+ unset export_module

########################################################################
#  clearMT removes the ModuleTable from your environment.  It is rarely
#  needed but it useful sometimes.

clearMT()
{
  eval $($LMOD_DIR/clearMT_cmd bash)
}

########################################################################
#  The following make the action of the settarg available to the titlebar
#  for both xterm's and screen but only for interactive shells.
if [ -n "${PS1:-}" ]; then
  if [ -n "${LMOD_FULL_SETTARG_SUPPORT:-}" -a "$LMOD_FULL_SETTARG_SUPPORT" != no ]; then
    xSetTitleLmod()
    {
      builtin echo -n -e "\033]2;$1\007";
    }
    SET_TITLE_BAR=:

    case "$TERM" in
      xterm*)
        SET_TITLE_BAR=xSetTitleLmod
        ;;
    esac

    SHOST=${SHOST-${HOSTNAME%%.*}}
    precmd()
    {
      eval $(${LMOD_SETTARG_CMD:-:} -s bash)
      ${SET_TITLE_BAR:-:} "${TARG_TITLE_BAR_PAREN}${USER}@${SHOST}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
      ${USER_PROMPT_CMD:-:}
    }

    # define the PROMPT_COMMAND to be precmd iff it isn't defined already.
    : ${PROMPT_COMMAND:=precmd}
  fi
fi
+ '[' -n '' ']'

########################################################################
#  Make tab completions available to bash users.

if [ ${BASH_VERSINFO:-0} -ge 3 ] && [ -r  /usr/share/lmod/lmod/init/lmod_bash_completions ] && [ -n "${PS1:-}" ]; then
 . /usr/share/lmod/lmod/init/lmod_bash_completions
fi
+ '[' 4 -ge 3 ']'
+ '[' -r /usr/share/lmod/lmod/init/lmod_bash_completions ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'

if [[ ${-/x} != $- ]]; then
   echo "End of Lmod init/bash script to define the module command"
fi
+ [[ hvBc != hvxBc ]]
+ echo 'End of Lmod init/bash script to define the module command'
End of Lmod init/bash script to define the module command

;cho 'arg is 'ACCESS-CM2_historical
' echo 'arg is ACCESS-CM2_historical
arg is ACCESS-CM2_historical
);R=$(echo /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
++ echo $'/nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical\r'
+ VAR=$'/nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical\r'
echo 'var is '$VAR;
' echo 'var is /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
var is /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
ls ${VAR}*.nc;
*.nc''/nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
*.nc: No such file or directory35080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
exit 1;
+ exit 1
```

Comment: I can imagine problems only if the lines contain special chars: whitespace, quotes, control characters. You should add the output of `head -n 1 /dir/subdir/File_Prefix_List.csv |  xargs -I {} bash -vxc "...` to your question. After that you should replace `VAR=\$(echo /dir/subdir/SharedPrefix_{})` with `VAR=\"/dir/subdir/SharedPrefix_{}\"`and `ls \${VAR}*.nc` with `ls \"\${VAR}\"*.nc`

Comment: Thanks very much @HaukeLaging for your fast response.
I have provided the output and error message that you requested in the post above. I hope this can be of use. It seems the wildcard is not read properly perhaps since the whole section is within double quotes..... (i.e. `... xargs ... bash -c "... ; ... ; ...*.nc..."`)

Comment: To add to the last comment, @HaukeLaging, when I made the changes to the `VAR=...` and `ls ...` as suggested I still get the same error message: `arg is ACCESS-CM2_historical  ;  
var is /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical
 ;  *.nc: No such file or directory35080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical`

Comment: to add to this I get the same error when running the simplified code:     `head -n 1 ~/wget_scripts/Model_Scen_Names.csv | xargs -I {} --max-procs 44 ls /nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_{}*.nc` 
     Therefore I think the issue must be from the combination of `{}` and `*`

Comment: Solution found. see edited post

Comment: Welcome to U&L, liaml! Please post any Answers down below in an Answer box, not in the Question itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the `bash -vx` output line

```
+ VAR=$'/nobackup/b9035080/NCdata_RealsPalau/Reals_Palau_tos_Oday_ACCESS-CM2_historical\r'
```

there is a carriage return (CR, `\r`) character at the end of the input lines. Unless the Unix line feed character (LF, `\n`) that is not stripped off and becomes part of the string which then, of course, does not match the filesystem paths any more.